# Set a member GlobalCEFApp->OnWebKitInitialized with function address C++ Builder

Tags: c++, delphi, c++builder, chromium-embedded, cef4delphi

I want to build a test application with CEF4.I have installed CEF4Delphi (github.com/salvadordf/CEF4Delphi) component to C++ Builder successfuly. And I want to build the JSExtension delphi demo project in C++ Builder.

I'm trying to set a function to a member, but each time a get same error:

[bcc32 Error] Unit1.cpp(35): E2235 Member function must be called or its address taken

I tried all of them:

```
//This is my function, just a global function
void GlobalCEFApp_OnWebKitInitialized();

//For GlobalCEFApp object I want to assign my function to a member function OnWebKitInitialized of that object 
 GlobalCEFApp = new TCefApplication();


// I tried this:

GlobalCEFApp->OnWebKitInitialized = GlobalCEFApp_OnWebKitInitialized;
GlobalCEFApp->OnWebKitInitialized = &GlobalCEFApp_OnWebKitInitialized;
GlobalCEFApp->OnWebKitInitialized = (_di_TOnWebKitInitializedEvent*)GlobalCEFApp_OnWebKitInitialized;
GlobalCEFApp->OnWebKitInitialized = reinterpret_cast<TOnWebKitInitializedEvent &>(GlobalCEFApp_OnWebKitInitialized);

//But only this compiled, however it gives access violation at runtime
GlobalCEFApp->OnWebKitInitialized = ( _di_TOnWebKitInitializedEvent &)GlobalCEFApp_OnWebKitInitialized;
```

How to do that correctly ?

I use CEF4Delphi (github.com/salvadordf/CEF4Delphi) component in C++ Builder. On delphi JSExtension demo project it is working good, but I cannot build the C++ version of the same demo. C++ uses delphi interfaces, and I don't know how to use it correctly. I need to assign my function to the member function for GlobalCEFApp->OnWebKitInitialized = ?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but why are you using `__fastcall`? A quick search (to find out if functions with that calling convention could have their address taken) and reading a few places seems to indicate that whatever "speedup" it might lead to might as well lead to "speed*downs*" instead.

Comment: I tried to use it as a member function of another Form class

Comment: Time to do something you should have done from the start: Create a [mcve] to show us. Also please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). What *is* `GlobalCEFApp_OnWebKitInitialized`? What *is* `GlobalCEFApp->OnWebKitInitialized`? And are you sure that you can take the address of a `__fastcall` function?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude "*are you sure that you can take the address of a `__fastcall` function?*" - yes, you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TCefApplication::OnWebKitInitialized` event is declared as using the `TOnWebKitInitializedEvent` type, which is declared in the `uCEFInterfaces.pas` unit as:

```pascal
TOnWebKitInitializedEvent = {$IFDEF DELPHI12_UP}reference to{$ENDIF} procedure() {$IFNDEF DELPHI12_UP}of object{$ENDIF};
```

CEF defines `DELPHI12_UP` in Delphi/C++Builder 2009 and later.

You did not say which version of C++Builder you are using.

- If you are using C++Builder 2007 or earlier, the `OnWebKitInitialized` event expects a pointer to a **non-static class method**.
- If you are using C++Builder 2009+, the `OnWebKitInitialized` event expects an [**anonymous method**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Anonymous_Methods_in_Delphi) instead.

Since you mention that you tried using `_di_TOnWebKitInitializedEvent`, which only exists if `TOnWebKitInitializedEvent` is an anonymous method type, I have to assume you are using C++Builder 2009+.

In C++, Delphi-style anonymous methods require special handling, which Embarcadero has documented:

[How to Handle Delphi Anonymous Methods in C++](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/How_to_Handle_Delphi_Anonymous_Methods_in_C%2B%2B)

You need to wrap `GlobalCEFApp_OnWebKitInitialized()` in order to use it as an anonymous event handler.  To do that, you have a couple of choices depending on whether you are using the classic Borland Win32/OSX compiler or one of the newer [Clang-based compilers](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Clang-enhanced_C%2B%2B_Compilers).

- **Classic**: You must write a functor that implements the `TOnWebKitInitializedEvent` interface:

  ```
  class TWebKitInitRef : public TCppInterfacedObject<TOnWebKitInitializedEvent>
  {
  public:
      INTFOBJECT_IMPL_IUNKNOWN(TInterfacedObject);
      void __fastcall Invoke() { GlobalCEFApp_OnWebKitInitialized(); }
  };

  GlobalCEFApp->OnWebKitInitialized = _di_TOnWebKitInitializedEvent(new TWebKitInitRef());
  ```
- **Clang**: You can use a C++ lambda:

  ```
  GlobalCEFApp->OnWebKitInitialized = [](){ GlobalCEFApp_OnWebKitInitialized(); };
  ```

Comment: Looks like the best answer to my question. I use XE7 and when I try this I get `[BCC32 Error] E2352 Cannot create instance of abstract class 'TMethodRef<TOnWebKitInitializedEvent,WebKitInit,void,_DummyType,_DummyType,_DummyType,_DummyType,_DummyType>'
   because of '_fastcall TOnWebKitInitializedEvent::Invoke() = 0'`

Comment: @AyayMatty apparently the `TMethodRef` in the docs does not provide a no-parameter overload for `Invoke()`. I have updated my answer with an alternative implementation.

Comment: Thank You! your answer resolved the question, but when I build and run, browser shows only white background and nothing shows, looks like it is trying to load a page but cannot display. I marked your answer as accepted, because my question is answered, but I still have issues with translating a small delphi demo to c++builder, caused I think by this member OnWebKitInitialized. Please if you have a chance to look at my new question and give an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55314087/translating-js-extension-demo-cef4delphi-from-delphi-to-cbuilder-fails-onweb

Answer (score 2):

Member functions must be qualified with the class they're in.

So you need to use `&TheClassOfTheFunction::GlobalCEFApp_OnWebKitInitialized`.

Comment: I tried this :GlobalCEFApp->OnWebKitInitialized = (& TCefApplication::OnWebKitInitialized) (GlobalCEFApp_OnWebKitInitialized); But it is not working, the class of the function is TCefApplication

Comment: @AyayMatty your `GlobalCEFApp_OnWebKitInitialized()` is not a method of the `TCefApplication` class

Comment: @RemyLebeau, No, this is my funtion, but I want to do this: `GlobalCEFApp = new TCefApplication(); GlobalCEFApp->OnWebKitInitialized = ( _di_TOnWebKitInitializedEvent &)GlobalCEFApp_OnWebKitInitialized;` I use CEF4Delphi (https://github.com/salvadordf/CEF4Delphi) component in C++ Builder. On delphi JSExtension demo project it is working good, but I cannot build the C++ version of the same demo. C++ uses delphi interfaces, and I don't know how to use it correctly. Please, maybe you can look and help with assigning my function address to the member function for GlobalCEFApp->OnWebKitInitialized

Comment: @AyayMatty see the answer I have posted